# Как сделать многооконное приложение в PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Я хочу сделать приложение, в котором перед его включением будет окно входа.

Данное окно должно появляться при запуске программы, после выполнения входа (то есть при корректном вводе данных) - это окно должно закрыться, после чего открыться главное окно.

Как это реализовать?

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from password_window import Ui_MainWindow



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**password_window.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(284, 258)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 284, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Адрес электронной почты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пароль:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зарегистрироватся"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">(c)Copyright print(&quot;infinity&quot;)</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick можете помочь с вопросом?

Comment: Settings, пожалуйста, покажите что вы уже написали и лучше расскажите - окно входа куда?

Comment: @S.Nick добавил существующий код.

Comment: Самый простой вариант использовать QStackedWidget. На одном стеке размещаешь форму входа, после валидации переключаешь на следующую страницу стека.

Comment: @EdwardGrachev в таком случаи, что мешает пользователю просто переключится на следующую страницу? Тем более от логина и пароля зависит тип открываемого окна, то есть администратор или обычный пользователь.

Comment: А как ты себе представляешь что он сам переключится? Стрелки на форме видны только во время конфигурирования. Если запустить приложение их не будет видно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
  

USER_PWD = {
    'userFrom@gmail.com': 'user',
    'admin@gmail.com': 'admin'
}


class SigninPage(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SigninPage, self).__init__()
        self.signin_user_label = QLabel('E-mail:')
        self.signin_pwd_label = QLabel('Password:')
        self.signin_pwd2_label = QLabel('Password:')
        self.signin_user_line = QLineEdit()
        self.signin_pwd_line = QLineEdit()
        self.signin_pwd2_line = QLineEdit()
        self.signin_button = QPushButton('Sign in')

        self.user_h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.pwd_h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.pwd2_h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.all_v_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineedit_init()
        self.pushbutton_init()
        self.layout_init()

    def layout_init(self):
        self.user_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_user_label)
        self.user_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_user_line)
        self.pwd_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_pwd_label)
        self.pwd_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_pwd_line)
        self.pwd2_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_pwd2_label)
        self.pwd2_h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_pwd2_line)

        self.all_v_layout.addLayout(self.user_h_layout)
        self.all_v_layout.addLayout(self.pwd_h_layout)
        self.all_v_layout.addLayout(self.pwd2_h_layout)
        self.all_v_layout.addWidget(self.signin_button)

        self.setLayout(self.all_v_layout)

    def lineedit_init(self):
        self.signin_pwd_line.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.signin_pwd2_line.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.signin_user_line.textChanged.connect(self.check_input_func)
        self.signin_pwd_line.textChanged.connect(self.check_input_func)
        self.signin_pwd2_line.textChanged.connect(self.check_input_func)

    def pushbutton_init(self):
        self.signin_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.signin_button.clicked.connect(self.check_signin_func)

    def check_input_func(self):
        if self.signin_user_line.text() and \
           self.signin_pwd_line.text() and \
           self.signin_pwd2_line.text():
            self.signin_button.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.signin_button.setEnabled(False)

    def check_signin_func(self):
        if self.signin_pwd_line.text() != self.signin_pwd2_line.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Wrong', 'Two Passwords Typed Are Not Same!')
        elif self.signin_user_line.text() not in USER_PWD:
            USER_PWD[self.signin_user_line.text()] = self.signin_pwd_line.text()
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Information', 'Register Successfully')
            self.close()
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Wrong', 'This Username Has Been Registered!')

        self.signin_user_line.clear()
        self.signin_pwd_line.clear()
        self.signin_pwd2_line.clear()


class WindowAdmin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<h1>Привет, {name}!</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        
class WindowUser(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 480)        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<h1>Привет, {name}!</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        

class Login(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300, 100)

        self.user_label = QLabel('E-mail address:', self)
        self.pwd_label = QLabel('Password:', self)
        self.user_line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.user_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.pwd_line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.pwd_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.login_button = QPushButton('Войти', self)
        self.signin_button = QPushButton('Зарегистрироватся', self)

        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineedit_init()
        self.pushbutton_init()
        self.layout_init()
        self.signin_page = SigninPage()            

    def layout_init(self):
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.user_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.user_line, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.pwd_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.pwd_line, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.login_button)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.signin_button)
        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)

        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

    def lineedit_init(self):
        self.user_line.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your email')
        self.pwd_line.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your password')
        self.pwd_line.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.user_line.textChanged.connect(self.check_input_func)
        self.pwd_line.textChanged.connect(self.check_input_func)

    def pushbutton_init(self):
        self.login_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.check_login_func)
        self.signin_button.clicked.connect(self.show_signin_page_func)

    def check_login_func(self):
        password = USER_PWD.get(self.user_line.text())
        if password != self.pwd_line.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Wrong', 'Wrong Username or Password!')
            return
        
        user = self.user_line.text().split('@')[0]
        if user == 'admin':
            self.windowAdmin = WindowAdmin(user)
            self.windowAdmin.show()
        else:
            self.windowUser = WindowUser(user)
            self.windowUser.show()
            
        self.close()   

    def show_signin_page_func(self):
        self.signin_page.exec_()

    def check_input_func(self):
        if self.user_line.text() and self.pwd_line.text():
            self.login_button.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.login_button.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Login()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> это то, что нужно. Но можете рассказать чуть подробнее про переходы между окнами? 
> Я просто не понимаю как вы связываете разные окна, и классы графики и логики.

1. Каждое окно - это отдельный класс (`WindowAdmin()`, `WindowUser()`, ...).
2. При корректном вводе данных, где-то в БД у вас должен быть
   признак пользователя ('admin', 'user', ...) и
   в зависимости от этого значения вы открываете то либо иное окно.
3. Новое окно открывается стандартным способом.

- Создается экземпляр класса :

  `self.windowAdmin = WindowAdmin(user)`
- Показываем новое окно:

  `self.windowAdmin.show()`
- Закрываем окно, которое было открыто ранее:

  `self.close()`

Comment: это то, что нужно. Но можете рассказать чуть подробнее про переходы между окнами?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как вы связываете разные окна, и классы графики и логики.

Comment: @Settings я добавил некоторое обновление в свой ответ, проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour